# Which operators should I override so that I can compare two vectors?

Tags: c++

Which operators should I override so that I can compare two vectors?

If I have a

```
vector<Object>
```

is it enough to override the == operator for Object?

Thanks

Comment: Well, it depends on how you want to compare them

Comment: Object? c++?  are you sure? what framework?

Comment: [None?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) **Edit** Oh I see what you mean. Your contained type needs to be [`EqualityComparable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/EqualityComparable), so yes, you need to provide a suitable `bool operator==(const Object&, const Object&)`.

Comment: sorry guys for some reason my post was not displayed properly, it is vector<Object>

Comment: You need to say more about `Object`. What is it ?

Comment: The point is that you have to specify what kind of comparison you want to perform.

Comment: If you want to do a sort operation you need to overload the operator <

Comment: Nope, no sort just comparison for equality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The operator == of vector actually compares if the content is equal, in that comparison the operator == of "Object" will be called and that is the operator that you want to define depending of the logic you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to implement `bool operator==(const Object &lhs, const Object &rhs)` and `operator!=` as well for convenience, which in the implementation will return the opposite of `operator==`.

When you provide one, I think it is better to provide both, otherwise clients of your code (the other developers) may be confused where there is no need to be. Writing one operator calling the other one allows you an easier maintenance.